# How can I change my username to scrambled letters? Is it even possible?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Sooooooo lately I have wanted to change my username BUT, I wanted to make it scrambled letters, but neither do I know how to change my username nor how to make it the constant changing letters.

Comment: Have you searched for possible solutions already?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The way this is done is using formatting characters not allowed in usernames, so it is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can make anything in Minecraft scrambled letters (called "obfuscated" in the code) by writing `§k` (U+00A7 k) before it. However, for [this very reason](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Formatting_codes), the § character is disallowed in entry in most things in the Minecraft GUI, requiring you to insert it with a level editor or external tool—and in regards to your particular use here, non-alphanumeric characters such as § are not allowed in Minecraft usernames (only ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_ are allowed).

However, if you have a third-party launcher, configuration edit, or mod that lets you launch with an arbitrary name, and if you join a server that is offline-mode/cracked (i.e. doesn't check that your name really belongs to a Minecraft account you logged in with), you *can* join that particular server with a §k name if it doesn't check explicitly for it. I have done that before.